# In magento image website logo image is shown broken in user inbox

Tags: html, image, magento

In magento transactional email website logo image is shown broken inside inbox. When I check resource code then there is a proxy code added by gmail before my image URL.

The image URL is

```
http://www.cellularglobe.com/skin/frontend/default/default//images/logo_email.gif
```

But gmail adds its code before the image URL like this:

```
ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/OUmlpNbh4kNVb8fLZ-qgnIkumc-qMhsU4puF4Ni-5rQ1QzGVqRZM4zFLEvvc4LNu0shslY_NiMi-3Y7UyY9KhlgXvnsYc5UF7QppXO97TMoGI2Xj2HRytbkrb4s283isthQkkS9R7w=s0-d-e1-ft#****www.cellularglobe.com/skin/frontend/default/default//images/logo_email.gif****
```

Comment: The resource is asking for `Authorization`

Comment: First of remove the restriction, so that the URL is publicly accessible, then Gmail will fetch it.

Answer (score 1):

The link contains HTTP authentication. So gmail can not access it directly in mail body. So you should remove that authentication.

Comment: how to remove authentication explain it in little detail